# Constructing a loop to check if the sum of digits of a number is divisible by 3

Tags: c, loops

I need to make a program in which between a given span of numbers, the program needs to find the numbers whose sum of digits is divisible by 3. After that, it needs to check if the sum is larger than 0 and if it's divisible by 4, and print the numbers which fulfill the aforementioned conditions.
This is what I tried:

```
include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a, b, sum, c, i, total, d;
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
for (i=a; i<b; i++)
{
  sum = 0;
  c = i;
  while (c != 0)
  {
   d=c%10;
    if ((d%10)%3 == 0)
    {
      sum = sum + d;
    }
      c = c /10;
    if (sum%4==0 && sum>0)
    {
      printf("%d\n", i);
      total++;
    }
   }
  }
  printf("%d", total);
 return 0;
}
```

I get a wrong output and I can't find the mistake. Any ideas?

Comment: what is `d`?...

Comment: The `while` loop sums the digits. The divisibility checks are done after that, but your `while` loop includes them. Perhaps you should choose a wider indentation, say 4 spaces, to make the program flow stand out better.

Comment: @coderredoc sorry I missed a line, edited it.

Comment: lot's of redundant thing...you can think what you want to do and then do it.

Comment: You are summing the digits only when the digit itself if divisible by 3... Start separating the sum from the divisibility check.

Comment: "I get a wrong output" -- Please be more specific when describing the error. Which output do you get and which output did you expect?

Comment: This entire program would benefit a lot from either "rubber duck debugging" or stepping through line by line with a software debugger, whichever is easier for you.

Comment: @MOehm for example when I enter 1 and 30, the output is -1470429632.

Comment: I found my mistake, I didn't declare the value of total in the beginning, it was returning garbage value at the end, thanks for the help.

Comment: Imagine how much simpler this assignment would be if you had a function called sumOfDigits(n), and a function called isDivisibleByThree(n).  The thing is, C lets you _write_ those functions yourself.  You can write them, and test them, and then when you're certain that they work, you can use them in a higher level program (e.g., in this assignment.)  The fact that you found this assignment challenging is proof that it's not too early to learn how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be broken into 2 parts:-

```
int DigitSum(int num)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while(num){
       sum += num%10;
       num/=10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Follow the `D-R-Y` principle. Do not repeat yourself. If you are doing that you can be sure that you are missing the chance of reusability.

Separate the independent reusable logic from the core functionality that is helpful once you get into big project.

Now you get into logic:

```
for(int i=a;i<=b;i++)
{
     int digSum = DigitSum(i);
     if( digSum > 0 && digSum%3 == 0 && digSum%4 == 0 ){
         printf("%d\n", i); 
         total++;
     }
}
printf("%d",total);
```

#### Where did you go wrong?

- In case a digit `d` is not divisble by `3` you are not considering it in the `sum` which is wrong.
- For a number like 6666 there will be 2 times when you increase `total` which is again wrong.